# Что делать если не работает вход в сайт,хотя код вроде бы правильный?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Всем привет!Проблема в том,что я не могу сделать вход, т.к он не находит его в базе данных и вечно мне отправляет "0" можете помочь?

```
<?php
session_start();

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','register');

if (!$connect) {
echo "Ошибка подключения к базе данных.";
} 

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$check_user = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND 
`password` = '$password'");
echo mysqli_num_rows($check_user);
```

Comment: Во-первых, у вас опасная SQL-инъекция. Во-вторых, а почему вы уверены, что в базе что-то есть?

Comment: Ну я проверил что в базе есть юзер,которого я создал

Comment: выполните ваш запрос к базе не из php, а из консоли или phpmyadmin или чем вы пользуетесь и посмотрите на результат

Comment: я 0 только учусь...могли бы вы мне скинуть источник где это написано?

Comment: Сделать перед запросом в базу echo "["$login"]" и тоже самое для $password. Возможно, там передаются не те данные что ожидаются. Квадратные скобки для того, что бы увидеть пробел или новую строку которая попадает в переменную. Например, ожидается что $login содержит test а по факту напечатается [test ]

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$login' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in

Comment: Пробовали ли вы тримить? И у вас не хешируется пароль... В базе вы храните пароли в открытом виде?

Comment: Да,в открытом виде...Я делаю просто хотя бы работало,что бы понять вообще как это,а потому уже ставить хеш и т.д